# Copy private key from OpenKeyChain to tails GPG?

Tags: encryption

I have a private PGP key on [OpenKeyChain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.keychain) that I'd like to move to tails.

There only seems to be one way to export from OpenKeyChain - choose to make the encrypted backup file? But I can't get the process to work.

- I made a backup from Android, "backup.sec.pgp" (Noting the passphrase of hyphenated numbers)
- Transferred it to tails
- Ran 'gpg --decrypt backup.sec.pgp | gpg --import backup.sec.pgp'

It returns:

```
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Format: numeric9x4
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Begin: 96
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Then I enter in the long hyphenated numerical passphrase and it spits out:

```
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
```

Advice would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo, I got confused as well.
The right command is:

```
gpg --decrypt backup_YYYY-MM-DD.pgp | gpg --import
```

you typed the file name twice.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this may sound "extra" but. I believe it will get the job done. try using this method on pc or a Mac with this

https://www.openkeychain.org/faq/#how-to-import-an-openkeychain-backup-with-gpg

then make a backup and move it to tails.

if You've found a better way I'm all ears as I currently have to go through this pain in the ass. such a pain but both, wonderful services.

gl